# how to display id and name in form_dropdown

Tags: codeigniter

i have data like this

kdae  |  name 
    1   |  MBC
    2   |  BBC
    3   |  CDC

i want to display inside my form_dropdown

```
<1 ---- MBC>
<2 ---- BBC>
<3 ---- CDC>
```

this my code in controller

```
$kdaes = $this->master_order->get_list_kdaes();
        $opt = array('' => 'All AE');
        foreach ($kdaes as $kdae) {
            $opt[$kdae] = $kdae;
        }
        $data['form_kdae'] = form_dropdown('',$opt,'','id="kdae" name="kdae" class="form-control"');
```

this is code in my model

```
public function get_list_kdaes()
    {
        $this->db->select('kdae','Nama');
        $this->db->from($this->table1);
        $this->db->order_by('kdae','asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

        $kdaes = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) 
        {
            $kdaes[] = $row->kdae;
        }
        return $kdaes;
    }
```

and code for my view

```
<input name="kodecat" type="text" hidden>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="kdae" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Kode AE</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <?php echo $form_kdae; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

but if i run my form_dropdown just display like this

```
1
2
3
```

theres any solution?

Comment: can you please show your data structure more in detail?

Comment: do you means my database?
tabel masterae with column kodeae and name
where inside column kodeae = 1, 2,3 and name = mbc, bbc, cdc

Answer (score 1):

syntax is `from_dropdown(name,options,selected_option,extra attribute )`

so it should be

```
 form_dropdown('kdae',$opt,'','id="kdae" class="form-control"');
```

Comment: hi JYoThI, that code still display just 1,2,3 where i want 1--MBC etc..

Answer (score 0):

You are having an unnecessary `foreach` loop in your model, just do:

```
return $query->result();
```

in your controller you retrieve the data returned from the model:

```
foreach ($kdaes as $row) {
    $opt[$row->kodeae] = $row->kodeae. ' --- '.$row->Nama;
}
```

hint: pay attention in your select clause, as you have columns with lowercase (kodae) and others with uppercase (Nama), check if this is corect...

Comment: maybe ur logic is correct but if im using ur code get error Message: Trying to get property of non-object but ill try to figure it with another code

Comment: ya vickel correct kodeae is lowercase and Nama is uppercase but the error Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public function get_list_kdaes()
{
    $this->db->select('kdae','Nama');
    $this->db->from($this->table1);
    $this->db->order_by('kdae','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $kdaes = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
        $kdaes[$row['kdae']] = $row['Nama'];
    }
    return $kdaes;
}
```

Comment: hi Shihas i get message Cannot use object of type stdClass as array for $kdaes[$row['kdae']] = $row['Nama']; there any solution?

Comment: try the updated answer. change `$result = $query->result();` to `$result = $query->result_array();`